# Spring data jpa continue batch insert on Exception

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

In my spring boot application I am trying to do batch inserts for improving write performance. The problem is that I get duplicate data on regular basis for which I have a few unique constraints on my table. When doing serial inserts I just catch DataIntegrityException and ignore them. But when doing batch inserts if even one insert fails, the whole batch is not saved. I want hibernate to still save the records that do not throw error.
I am using repository.saveAll() for inserts and my database is Mysql

Answer (score 0):

In your batch process, you need to add

```
 .faultTolerant()
 .skipPolicy(new AlwaysSkipItemSkipPolicy())
```

in the step that is doing it after the writer . for example , in my step , i've configured it like this

```
@Bean
 public Step step1(){
      return steps.get("step1")
              .<Product,Product>chunk(3)
              .reader(reader(null))
              .processor(new ProductProcessor())
              .writer(flatFileItemWriter(null))
             //  .writer(xmlWriter(null))
             // .writer(dbWriter())
             //   .writer(dbWriter2())
              .faultTolerant()
              .skipPolicy(new AlwaysSkipItemSkipPolicy())
              .listener(new ProductSkipListener())
              .build();
 }
```

This will only get half the job done since you would also like to see at the end the records that couldn't be added. for that you need to add listener which basically implements the logic on how to handle the cases where object hasn't been written to the db.

Comment: Isn't this applicable for Spring batch applications? My application is of type spring boot.

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible. The internal structures of Hibernate simply don't work anymore after an exception occurred. You will have to catch the exception and retry your operation in a fresh transaction/entity manager.